# how to retrieve firebase data in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

im trying to fetch data from firebase database, which im getting the data very well, but when i try to push all items received in an array, i obtain an array which i cannot iterate through like any other javascript array. here is my code:

```
var li = [];
  
  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDB
      .database()
      .ref("collection")
      .on("value", (data) => {
        let all = data;
        
        all.forEach((element) => {
          
          li.push(element.val());
        });
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(li);
```

when i do `console.log(li)` , i get the `li` array which seems okay with the data, but when i try to do something with the array e.g. if i do `console.log(li.length)` , it prints `0` yet the array has multiple items in it. the problem is that my `li` array doesnt behave like an array. please assist me locate where the problem could be

Answer (score 1):

You can't push data like that. Try this code.

```
    const [arr,setArr] = useState([]);
      

      useEffect(()=>{
      firebaseDB
      .database()
      .ref("collection")
      .on("value", (snapshot) =>{
        let data = [];
        snapshot.forEach((child)=>{
          data.push(child.val());
        })
       setArr(data);
      });
     
  },[])
```

Comment: that worked. but ihad to set `setArr(data);` inside the on()

Comment: oops. Sorry I just put it mistakenly.

Answer (score -2):

use forEach keyword to iterate. it works